# Applying \lowercase to index entries

Tags: indexing, sorting, capitalization

I would like to sort the index entries independent of case.

Initially I was getting (code provided in MWE) the image on the left. So, that *seemed* like an easy fix: just apply `\lowercase` (uncomment the `\def` in the MWE) but that yields the image on the right:

[image]
[image]

So, how do I get these sorted alphabetically, and get the two entries for `zero` to be displayed as a sub-entries under a single heading?

### Failed Attempts:

1. I thought this was an explansion issue, so I tried to use

   ```
   \edef\LowerCaseWord{\lowercase{#2}}
   \index{\LowerCaseWord!#1}
   ```

   but this also yielded results identical to the image on the right.
2. Since a wise member here (who I think no longer wants to be associated with this comment :-)) once alluded that a few carefully placed `\expandafter`s should fix anything I tried this and it also does not change the output:

   ```
   \edef\LowerCaseWord{\lowercase{#2}}
   \expandafter\index{\LowerCaseWord!#1}
   ```

### Code:

```
%\def\UseLowercase{}% Uncomment to use lowercase

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\ifdefined\UseLowercase% Select whether we use lowercase or not
    \newcommand{\IndexTitle}{Index (lowercase)}%
\else
    \newcommand{\IndexTitle}{Index}%
    \renewcommand{\lowercase}[1]{#1}%
\fi

\newcommand*{\AddIndexEntry}[2]{%
    % #1 = indexed term, #2 = word to index this under
    \par\noindent
    Indexing: #2
    \index{\lowercase{#2}!#1}
}%

\makeindex[title={\IndexTitle},columns=1]

\begin{document}
    \AddIndexEntry{aardvark}{aardvark}
    \AddIndexEntry{Saved by Zero}{Saved}
    \AddIndexEntry{Saved by Zero}{Zero}
    \AddIndexEntry{zero}{zero}
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\lowercase` isn't expandable, so no amount of `\expandafter` can do. But there's something that can be done. Be patient. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd say that

```
\newcommand*{\AddIndexEntry}[2]{%
    % #1 = indexed term, #2 = word to index this under
    \par\noindent
    \lowercase{\def\temp{#2}}%
    Indexing: #2%
    \expandafter\index\expandafter{\temp!#1}%
}
```

should be what you need.

How does `\lowercase` works? It sends its argument to a further processor (it's *not* a macro, so it doesn't its work in TeX's “mouth”); the token list is converted using the `\lccode` table: each character token that hasn't a zero `\lccode` is converted to its lowercase correspondent, but symbolic tokens such as `\def` or `\temp` are untouched. The token list so obtained is put back in the input as if it had been there from the beginning. There's *no* expansion during this process: so if TeX finds `\lowercase{\def\temp{Xyz}}` when it's executing things, then it "waits" a bit, processes the token list as explained,  then it processes

```
\def\temp{xyz}
```

and goes along.

---

In case you have more than one index, you can use a modified form:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\newcommand*{\AddIndexEntry}[3][]{%
  % #1 = indexed term, #2 = word to index this under
  \par\noindent
  \lowercase{\def\temp{#3}}%
  Indexing: #3%
  \if!#1!
    \expandafter\index\expandafter{\temp!#2}%
  \else
    \expandafter\indexopt\expandafter{\temp!#2}{#1}
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\indexopt}[2]{\index[#2]{#1}}

\makeindex
\makeindex[name=Name,title=Title,columns=1]

\begin{document}

\AddIndexEntry{aardvark}{aardvark}
\AddIndexEntry{Saved by Zero}{Saved}
\AddIndexEntry{Saved by Zero}{Zero}
\AddIndexEntry[Name]{zero}{zero}

\printindex
\printindex[Name]

\end{document}
```

The `\indexopt` macro takes care of switching the arguments, so that the `\expandafter` doesn't need to jump over the optional argument to `\index`.

Comment: Well, it definitely does what I need, but have to ask: what does it mean to apply a macro like `\lowercase` to a `\def`?  Don't think I have seen that kind of voodoo magic before.

Answer (score 1):

Following egreg's answer, for those who just need a 1-argument version and have the lowercase words in the table:

```
\newcommand{\lindex}[1]{%
  \lowercase{\def\temp{#1}}%
  \expandafter\index\expandafter{\temp}%
}
```

Comment: Following this, I am using a command that takes the word "ExampleWord" and adds "exampleword" to the index, while displaying "ExampleWord" in the text (so I don't need to type it twice):
`\newcommand\indlt[1]{#1 \lowercase{\def\temp{#1}}  \expandafter\index\expandafter{\temp}}`.
However, this throws a weird error when the ExampleWord is in the section header, i.e. `\section{\indlt{ExampleWord}}`. Can you help?

Comment: Maybe try \section{\protect\indlt{ExampleWord}} ?

Comment: Using `\newcommand\indltneu[1]{#1\lowercase{\def\temp{#1}}\expandafter\index\expandafter{\temp}}` and then `\subsection{\protect\indltneu{Normal Distribution} and Lognormal Distribution}` results in in "undefined control sequence" upon second run of `pdflatex`, probably when when the TOC is generated: `Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...tname }{\numberline {10.3}\indltneu 
                                                  {Normal Distribution} and ...
l.32 ...ormal Distribution}{16}{subsection.1.10.3}`