# texindy/imakeidx book marks point to incorrect pages with multiple indices

Tags: hyperref, indexing, subdividing, imakeidx

I have two indexes: the `Main Index` and `Name Index`.  The PDF books are visually correct:

[image]

Note that the `Name Index` starts on Page 6, and the `Z` entry for the `Name Index` is on Page 7.

However, up clicking on the `Z` in the `Name Index` (which appears on Page 7) I am taken to the `Z` for the `Main Index` (Page 6).

This code is adapted form [Applying \lowercase to index entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51688/applying-lowercase-to-index-entries).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
    \clearpage%
    \section*{#1}%
    \pdfbookmark[0]{#1}{#1}% 
    \nopagebreak%
}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51688/applying-lowercase-to-index-entries
\newcommand*{\AddIndexEntry}[3][]{%
  % #1 = indexed term, #2 = word to index this under
  \par\noindent
  \lowercase{\def\temp{#3}}%
  Indexing: #3%
  \if!#1!
    \expandafter\index\expandafter{\temp!#2}%
  \else
    \expandafter\indexopt\expandafter{\temp!#2}{#1}
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\indexopt}[2]{\index[#2]{#1}}

\makeindex[title={Main Index},columns=1,program=texindy]
\makeindex[title={Name Index},columns=1,program=texindy,name=Name]

\begin{document}

\AddIndexEntry{aardvark}{aardvark}
\AddIndexEntry{Saved by Zero}{Saved}
\AddIndexEntry{Saved by Zero}{Zero}
\AddIndexEntry[Name]{zero}{zero}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{}{Main Index}
\printindex

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{}{Name Index}
\printindex[Name]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than doing manual bookmark placement, I believe it's better to let `hyperref` work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand*\lettergroup[1]{\subsection{#1}}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51688/applying-lowercase-to-index-entries
\newcommand*{\AddIndexEntry}[3][]{%
  % #1 = indexed term, #2 = word to index this under
  \par\noindent
  \lowercase{\def\temp{#3}}%
  Indexing: #3%
  \if!#1!
    \expandafter\index\expandafter{\temp!#2}%
  \else
    \expandafter\indexopt\expandafter{\temp!#2}{#1}
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\indexopt}[2]{\index[#2]{#1}}

\makeindex[title={Main Index},columns=1,program=texindy]
\makeindex[title={Name Index},columns=1,program=texindy,name=Name]
\indexsetup{level=\section}

\begin{document}

\AddIndexEntry{aardvark}{aardvark}
\AddIndexEntry{Saved by Zero}{Saved}
\AddIndexEntry{Saved by Zero}{Zero}
\AddIndexEntry[Name]{zero}{zero}

\clearpage % we want to be sure that all index entries are output
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\printindex

\printindex[Name]
\end{document}
```

The key is, however, to use `\subsection` for the letter groups, so that they will be children to the index. With `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` we disable the numbering, and with `\indexsetup{level=\section}` we tell LaTeX to use `\section{\indexname}` instead of `\section*` so that the important actions by `hyperref` will be performed automatically.

Comment: So, I understand why `\indexsetup{\level=\section*}` don't print in TOC. Thanks for you solution !