# Duplicate entries in index when using lowercase

Tags: indexing, capitalization

I'm trying to create an index for my thesis and I have a custom command that outputs the index term inline and adds it to the index as well. I want to ignore spaces of terms so I issue a `\lowercase` to the argument. The issue however is that two terms which differ in case get treated as different index entries. MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{index}

%\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
%[program=texindy] % Same problem with texindy as well. 

\newcommand{\mindex}[1]{#1\index{\lowercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum 
Some important \mindex{object} here.
\newpage 
Another more important \mindex{Object} here as well.  
\lipsum 

\printindex 

\end{document}
```

So, what's the issue here? Also, is this a good way of putting stuff in index or should I be doing something smarter?

Comment: Perhaps [Applying \lowercase to index entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51688/applying-lowercase-to-index-entries) will help. Let us know if that answers your question. If so then we can close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks. (Search didn't unearth that link ... Apologies for that.)