# How can I get get makeindex to ignore capital letters?

Tags: indexing, capitalization

I've created a macro which highlights a word and sends it to the index

```
\newcommand{\indexthis}[1]{\textcolor{Maroon}{\textbf{#1}}\index{\MakeLowercase{#1}@{#1}}\xspace).
```

However the `\MakeLowercase` command does not appear to work as words which appear at the beginning of the sentence are sent to the `.idx` file with the capital letter in place. This then affects the sort order of the index as the capitalised words come first. Here's a minimal worked example

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\indexthis}[1]{\textcolor{Maroon}{\textbf{#1}}\index{\MakeLowercase{#1}@{#1}}\xspace}

\makeindex
%================================================================================================
\begin{document}

\indexthis{Aardvarks} keep out of the sun \\
\indexthis{Badgers} prefer the shade \\
But \indexthis{antelopes} adore sunshine \\
And \indexthis{lions} are sun addicts \\

\printindex

\end{document}
```

And here is a screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

The problem is that we have two A-Z lists, one for words which begin with uppercase letters, and one for words which begin with lowercase letters. Can anyone make changes to the macro to force the argument `#1` into lowercase before sending it to the `.idx` file? Alternatively is there a way to get `makeindex` to ignore capital letters during sorting? Ta.

(NB there's a thread [Applying `\lowercase` to index entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51688/applying-lowercase-to-index-entries) which deals partly with this issue. However, the solution is a macro containing two arguments. I'm trying to both highlight and add to the index using only one argument, and I haven't been able to adapt this code)

Comment: to actually run, your example needs `\usepackage{xspace}`.  if you don't care whether some of your index entries start with uppercase letters, then `\newcommand{\indexthis}[1]{\textcolor{Maroon}{\textbf{#1}}\index{#1}\xspace}` would have them sorted in the right alphabetical order -- ordinarily, `makeindex` doesn't make a distinction.

Comment: It's working now, and I don't understand what you did except remove the \lowercase command. Is it just a case of running makeindex enough times?

Comment: what i did was remove the `\MakeLowercase{#1}@` and extra braces.  so an entry with an initial caps will be sorted separately from an all-lowercase entry, and if two entries are otherwise the same (say "Aardvark" and "aardvark"), you will get two entries in the index -- but sorted next to one another.

Comment: Brill. So it was just a case of curly brackets after all that?

Comment: i haven't checked this, but i think it may be at least partly a case of the `\MakeLowercase` not being expanded at the right time.  the argument of an `\index` command is written out verbatim (one should check to see what actually gets into the .idx file), and the whole shebang is then sorted by a "dumb" ascii sort.  the extra braces may play a part, but that needs checking.  i *will* look into this; i'm writing a tome on how to abolish stealthy glitches, and this looks like something i hadn't yet considered.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps

```
\newcommand{\indexthis}[1]{\textcolor{Maroon}{\textbf{#1}}\lowercase{\index{#1}}}
```

(deleted xspace as it is not needed here as the macro call ends with `}` so does not drop spaces)

Answer (score 3):

Are you also concerned about singular/plural use? For example, it would be more usual to have a single index entry for `lion` rather than separate index entries for `lion` and `lions`? Here's a possible way of adjusting for singular/plural/uppercase/lowercase:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[style=index]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{\indexname}
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textmd{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{Maroon}{#1}}

\newcommand*{\newterm}[2][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#2}{name={#2},description={\nopostdesc},#1}%
}

\newterm{lion}
\newterm{aardvark}
\newterm{badger}
\newterm{antelope}

\begin{document}

\Glspl{lion} or \gls{lion}.
\Gls{lion} or \glspl{lion}.

\Glspl{aardvark} or \gls{aardvark}.
\Gls{aardvark} or \glspl{aardvark}.

\Glspl{badger} or \gls{badger}.
\Gls{badger} or \glspl{badger}.

\Glspl{antelope} or \gls{antelope}.
\Gls{antelope} or \glspl{antelope}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The result looks like:

[image: Image of resulting document]

The `makeindex` call is now

```
makeindex -s "test.ist" -t "test.glg" -o "test.gls" "test.glo"
```

where the document is called `test.tex`. Alteratively, you can just do `makeglossaries test`.